# Columns limitation in SSIS Excel Destination

Tags: excel, ssis

Am trying to query a table with 260 columns and write to an Excel output.

In Excel Destination -> Name of the Excel Sheet -> I clicked on NEW and tried to take the default data table.

However, I get a Microsoft JET Engine: Too many fields error message.

Writing to an existing file is giving me a 64-bit error message. I have the "Run 64bit Runtime" set to False in Project Properties.

Is there any way I can make this Export to Excel work?

Answer (score 0):

jet 4.0 engine writes to .xls files. these files have a limit of 256 columns iirc.

if you want to write to .xlsx files, use/install the microsoft ace 12.0 engine. there is 32-bit and 64-bit versions. but beware: match the "bitness" of your OS and installed Office.

a more programmatic way would be to use the epplus or npoi .net libraries, which read/write directly with the Excel file formats. the coding is much like you would do if using the Excel COM objects.

I've done this by having my SQL-Excel data transfer code in Poershell scripts, using Epplus.dll. then Ssis invokes the powershell scrips.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose the procedure would be the same as invoking a .NET or VB Script from SSIS?