# SSIS: Excel Source Stops adding columns after 258 columns

Tags: excel, ssis

I need to load a table that has 707 columns.  I have an excel data source in SSIS that can't create a table that also has 707 columns. It stops creating a columns after the 258 column.  Any Ideas how to create and load a table using SSIS that has 707 columns?

Comment: Maybe this helps you  [Columns limitation in SSIS Excel Destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46614263/columns-limitation-in-ssis-excel-destination)

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be you have to open Advanced Editor, Input and Output Properties Tab, Open Flat File Source Output, and begin manually assigning data types and column lengths that will match or be less than your source columns sizes.  For some reason, I can't get the regular editor to automatically assign the correct values after the 258th column in my .CSV file. This is a painful solution, but it also the only one that I could find that works.